# How can I take XML attribute and find a file that matches the attribute value in a given directory java

Tags: java, xml, directory

I have a java program that reads an xml file and grabs an attribute and prints that value to the screen. Now I would like to take the value of each attribute and search a directory to find all the files that match that given attribute.

My code is as follows:

```
    public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("////Orders//188219.outorder");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("seln_part");
        File dir = new File("////Images//Parts");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                FileFilter filter;
                System.out.println("Part Number : " + eElement.getAttribute("partNumber"));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I now would like to take `eElement.getAttribute("partNumber")`'s value and search the images/parts directory for any matches.

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attain this with below two steps.

Step 1:
Store all file names & Its absolute paths in hashmap like below,

```
HashMap<String,String> fileNamevsPathMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
String rootDirectory = "Your Directory Path to Search";
boolean isRecursive = true;
Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(rootDirectory, null, isRecursive);
for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    File file = (File) iterator.next();
    fileNamevsPathMap .put(file.getName(),file.getAbsolutePath()
}
```

Step 2: Use the hash map to search your matches

```
if(fileNamevsPathMap.containsKey(eElement.getAttribute("partNumber"))){
     System.out.println("Part Number absolute path : "+fileNamevsPathMap.get(eElement.getAttribute("partNumber")));
}else{
     System.out.println("Part Number Not found on directory");
}
```